# How to get the required shape in numpy.linalg.norm

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

If i have an numpy array

```
A=[[-4. -4. -4.]    #(6,3)
[-8. -8. -8.]
[-1. -1. -1.]
[-5. -5. -5.]
[ 2.  2.  2.]
[-2. -2. -2.]]
```

I need norm of each row as (2,3)
My solution is:

```
np.linalg.norm(A,axis=1)
```

My output is

```
[6.92820323  13.85640646   1.73205081   8.66025404   3.46410162  3.46410162]
```

Required output is:

```
[[  6.92820323  13.85640646]
[  1.73205081   8.66025404]
[  3.46410162   3.46410162]]
```

I want to get the required output just in one step without reshaping the resultant numpy array.because i have a large data set and i have to perform this operation repeatedly.
Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that's worth the trouble? Reshaping is cheap:

```
a = np.random.random((6,3))
timeit(lambda: np.linalg.norm(a, axis=-1), number=10**6)
# 5.118775532988366

a = np.random.random((6,))
timeit(lambda: a.reshape(3, 2), number=10**6)
# 0.36718635002034716
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ndarray.reshape()` to solve it

```
A=[[-4., -4., -4.],   #(6,3)
[-8., -8., -8.],
[-1., -1., -1.],
[-5., -5., -5.],
[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
[-2., -2., -2.]]
A = np.array(A)
ans = np.linalg.norm(A,axis=1).reshape((3,2))
```

Comment: As i mentioned i want this without reshaping the resultant numpy array.

Comment: I'm sorry,I did not see that.You want to solve it in one step or in only one line of code?